# How To delete Sheet rows in a worksheet in excel using office.js

Tags: office-js

My aim is to Clear the sheet of all data.

I have tried **worksheet.getusedRange().clear()** method, but it clears only the data and format but hidden rows still remain hidden. Even **worksheet.getUsedRange().delete('up')** doesn't remove the unhide property of rows.

The only workaround I found was to do **worksheet.getUsedRange.rowHidden = False** and then do **worksheet.getUsedRange().delete()** which will unhide the rows in the working range but it won't unhide the rows beyond it (i.e if data/format are present up to row10 but row 100 is hidden then this method won't unhide the 100th row)

And when I try **worksheet.getRange().rowHidden = false**, Then it throws an error -> "error: InvalidOperation: This operation is not permitted for the current object."

Is there any way to delete sheet Rows like in excel UI so that even the hidden property of the rows is also deleted.

I am using Excel Online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, the `getUsedRange` method only returns the range of cells that contain data or formatting. If the sheet contains hidden/empty rows beyond the range of cells that contains data/formatting, those hidden/empty rows won't be included in the range that the `getUsedRange` method returns.

To achieve your goal of clearing the sheet of all data, including any empty but hidden rows, you might consider doing something like this:

1. Use the `getRange` method to retrieve a range that you're confident is reasonably large enough to encompass any data (and/or empty, hidden rows) on the sheet.
2. Unhide all rows in that range.
3. Delete that range.

The following code sample illustrates this approach. Notice that it's specifying range `A1:KK20000` -- but you could set this to whatever value you feel is reasonably large enough to encompass data (and/or empty, hidden rows) on the sheet.

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    const range = sheet.getRange('A1:KK20000');
    range.rowHidden = false;
    range.delete(Excel.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
    context.sync();
});
```

Alternatively, you could use the API to delete the worksheet and then immediately create a new (empty) like-named sheet in its place...although this may be more visually disrupting to the user than the first approach I've described.